# Reading memory array

Tags: digital-logic, memory

im new to memory cells.
I have taken the below image from a video, i wanted to ask in the video he explains that the MUX can select 8 bits, but how is this even possible?
The output of a MUX is always 1 value isnt it?
Does he mean a series of MUX's to select 8 bits from 16bits?
He's using 1 bit to select 8bits through a MUX

[image]

Comment: 16:8 multiplexers are not hard to find. A multiplexer doesn't have to have just one output, it could have any number. Of course, you don't see many discrete logic devices anymore, so they're not as common anymore as discrete devices simply due to lack of demand.

Comment: The `0` and `1` in the drawing refer to the MUX's *select input* not the data it is passing.

Answer (score 1):

It's shorthand for "an array of multiplexers that switch together".

> Does he mean a series of MUX's to select 8 bits from 16bits?

Yes.